# How can i turn a INT to VARCHAR in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a database for my database class.

I have been trying to change the INT from SUBJECT_ID to VARCHAR.
This is the code I have been using but it keeps giving me errors:

```
ALTER TABLE COURSE
ALTER COLUMN SUBJECT_ID VARCHAR(11);
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),SUBJECT_ID) FROM COURSE;
```

and this is the table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE
(COURSE_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
SUBJECT_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
COURSE_GRADE_LEVEL CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
FAC_ID INT NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(FAC_ID) REFERENCES FACULTY(FAC_ID));
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am getting "ERROR 1064(42000): you have an error in your SQL syntax". i just dont know what.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for the `ALTER TABLE` statement? It explains it very clearly.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE COURSE MODIFY SUBJECT_ID VARCHAR(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(subject_id as varchar(11)) as subject_id_str from course
```

Comment: he wants to modify the table schema, not just return the value.

Comment: that was not clear to me barmar -- he tried both things, did you read past the first line?